# Kubuntu 18.04.2 will not upgrade

Tags: kubuntu

I have Kubuntu 18.04.2 running on my home built tower pc. This Kubuntu was fist installed as Kubuntu 17.10 64 bit on November 2, 2017.

Along the way I kept it upgraded and like I said, it's now at 18.04.2. When 18.04 came out I wanted to stay on the LTS track. I don't remember how I got from 17.10 to 18.04.2.

I haven't been using Kubuntu for a while until lately. Now I found out that Kubuntu LTS is at 18.04.4 so I tried to upgrade it.

Well, it won't upgrade, not even to 18.04.3.

I was poking around here on "ask ubuntu" and found a couple of hints.

Right now my system is fully updated according to apt:

```
root@eagle-kubuntu:~# apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]       
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]                 
Fetched 252 kB in 1s (238 kB/s)                                                             
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
root@eagle-kubuntu:~#
```

When I run dist-upgrade I get this:

```
root@eagle-kubuntu:~# apt dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@eagle-kubuntu:~#
```

I read somewhere that I might need to make sure "linux-image-generic" is installed, so when I run "# apt install linux-image-generic" I get this:

```
root@eagle-kubuntu:~# apt install linux-image-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.15.0.88.80).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
root@eagle-kubuntu:~#
```

For info, here is my lsb-release file:

```
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$
```

So my question is, is there any way to fix this without doing a reinstall?

Thanks for your input.

Here are my outputs from running 'sudo apt update', and 'sudo apt full-upgrade':

```
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for jcig: 
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease       
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease      
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done                     
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ 
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ 
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ 
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ sudo apt full-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$
```

Output of 'apt policy base-files', :

```
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ sudo apt policy base-files
[sudo] password for jcig: 
base-files:
  Installed: 10.1ubuntu2.8
  Candidate: 10.1ubuntu2.8
  Version table:
 *** 10.1ubuntu2.8 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.1ubuntu2.2 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
     10.1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$
```

I *think* I might know what happened. I also have Linuxmint installed on this machine. I use it as the "master" Grub distro. Meaning that I use it to keep Grub up to date on sda. It used to be that when I ran `update-grub` on Linuxmint, that other Ubuntu installs would show up in the Grub menu simply as "Ubuntu-...". So, here in Kubuntu I edited the lsb-release file's "DISTRIB_ID" line to something like "Kubuntu ..." so that it would show up in the menu as Kubuntu. I have since discovered that I no longer have to do that. So I recently changed this Kubuntu lsb-release file back to original. So, might that have caused this issue?

Output of `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files`,

```
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ sudo apt install --reinstall base-files
[sudo] password for jcig: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/59.9 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 230458 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../base-files_10.1ubuntu2.8_amd64.deb ...
Warning: Stopping motd-news.service, but it can still be activated by:
  motd-news.timer
Unpacking base-files (10.1ubuntu2.8) over (10.1ubuntu2.8) ...
Setting up base-files (10.1ubuntu2.8) ...
motd-news.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text (0.9.3-1ubuntu7.18.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for cracklib-runtime (2.9.2-5build1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for plymouth-theme-kubuntu-text (1:18.04ubuntu11) ...
dpkg: warning: version '/etc/lsb-release' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit
rmdir: failed to remove '/lib/plymouth/': No such file or directory
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for install-info (6.5.0.dfsg.1-2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.9) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
W: initramfs-tools configuration sets RESUME=UUID=55b8765f-38ea-41c3-a3b3-a357234bd848
W: but no matching swap device is available.
I: The initramfs will attempt to resume from /dev/sda9
I: (UUID=0f0586fe-6d88-4932-be6a-04beb11e0939)
I: Set the RESUME variable to override this.
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$
```

Latest output of 'cat /etc/lsb-release`:

```
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"
[jcig@eagle-kubuntu ~]$
```

Comment: First, there's no need to run as `root`. In fact, you can harm your system by using `root` indiscriminately. Run as your normal user and use `sudo` when you want elevated privileges. Second instead of `apt dist-upgrade`, please try `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Thank you, DK, for correcting me on the use of sudo, duly noted.

Comment: @DKBose, see the outputs above.

Comment: What's the output of `apt policy base-files`?

Comment: @OrganicMarble, See above for output of 'apt policy base-files'. Am I doing this right, or can I post answers to questions here?

Comment: You did it right. Ok, something is weird here. That package base-files is what sets the version number. And you have the version installed that should give you 18.04.4

Comment: Sudo is not needed for this next command. Try `cat /etc/issue` and see what the version it gives is.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, `Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS \n \l`

Comment: Thanks! So your system is indeed really ".4" and the question is why is that not showing up in other places.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, see above for my latest comment.

Comment: @HighFive I think you have answered it.  You could try doing a `sudo apt install --reinstall base-files` to get the '.4' to show up everywhere. But that is just a guess, I have not tested it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, I'll give it a try.

Comment: See above for latest outputs.

Comment: Hey, I just remembered that I made a copy of the original lsb-release file before I edited it. Should I put that one back in and then rerun the `apt install --reinstall base-files` command?

Comment: If you look here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/base-files/filelist you'll see that lsb-release is supposed to be in that package. You might have to purge on the apt command, or maybe the permissions are changed, who knows?  I think I've spent my silver bullet on this one. Best wishes!

Comment: I did notice this warning in your latest edit `dpkg: warning: version '/etc/lsb-release' has bad syntax: version number does not start with digit` I've no clue what caused that but I bet it is why it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I admit, I broke the system. I'm just going to install 18.04.4 when I get the time to do so. Thanks to all who helped, especially Organic Marble.

Comment: Would it be safe to purge the base-files, and then reinstall the base-files package?

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading using [do-release-upgrade](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html):

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

> The recommended way to upgrade a Server Edition installation is to use
>   the do-release-upgrade utility. Part of the update-manager-core
>   package, it does not have any graphical dependencies and is installed
>   by default.
>
> Debian based systems can also be upgraded by using apt dist-upgrade.
>   However, using do-release-upgrade is recommended because it has the
>   ability to handle system configuration changes sometimes needed
>   between releases.

In some cases [it does not work](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-18-04):

> When I run sudo do-release-upgrade It says: `Please install all
>   available updates for your release before upgrading.` and no upgrade
>   happened.
>
> I was able to fix this issue by running `sudo do-release-upgrade -c`

Then run `sudo do-release-upgrade` command again.